# How to open a link given on jsp in browser

Tags: java, jsp

I have given a link on the jsp , which is a dynamic value and I am printing it on the jsp by using - "s:property value="link" /". When the user is clicking on it, the link value gets appended with the url of my project , and hence is not gettig opened.I want it should get opened as an independent link. I am using java. Please give a soln for the above.

```
<s:if test="link!=null"> 
<td style="cursor:hand;color: #0000FF" onclick="window.open('<s:property value="link"/>','_blank')">
<s:property value="link" />
</td>
```

Comment: can u please post the code. Most likely you need to chose correctly between redirect or forward?

Comment: <s:if test="link!=null">
        <td style="cursor:hand;color: #0000FF" onclick="window.open('<s:property value="link"/>','_blank')"><s:property value="link" /></td>
      </s:if>

Comment: @S111 printing it on the jsp by using ...?  If you put some code definately you will find help here..

Comment: ex. If I am writing www.google.com in the link value, the link is being opened in the browser as http://localhost:9080/EGovProject/www.google.com

Comment: @Viraj Nalawade I have already given the code

Comment: Should the link not be `<s:url value="link">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you forgot to add scheme (http) in the beginning of the URL.

This would make it a relative link and be appended to your current address.

If you do not know the scheme (http or https) you can start with // instead, and scheme will be inherited from current page.

```
<td style="cursor:hand;color: #0000FF" onclick="window.open('//<s:property value="link"/>','_blank')">
    <s:property value="link" />
</td>
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly the problem.. @S111 this looks as right solution to me.. Just add 'http' to link value..

Comment: It would be really nice If u would edit the above code for the solution

Comment: @S111 Just add 'http://' to link value or replace your td tag with this _<td style="cursor:hand;color: #0000FF" onclick="window.open('<s:property value="http://"+"link"/>','_blank')">_

Comment: I have one more query. If the user provides the link with already written http or https , then what would be the solution

Comment: You had not posted your code when I posted my reply, but Ive added full code now. With // to inherit scheme. Pls test!